# How to fix "The exit status code '-1073741819' " in Laravel using wkhtmltopdf to download pdf?

Tags: laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to create an export button which converts an HTML page to PDF then downloads it.

I'm using Windows 10, XAMPP, Laravel 5.8, wkhtmltopdf.

Here is the error screenshot :
[image]

**Snappy Config:**

```
'pdf' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => '"F:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"',   
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
'image' => [
    'enabled' => true,
    'binary'  => '"F:\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe"',
    'timeout' => false,
    'options' => [],
    'env'     => [],
],
```

**Export Code** :

```
    $export_data = $this->exportData($checklist, $request);

    $pdf_content = view('checklist.pdf.content')->with($export_data);

    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($pdf_content);
    $pdf->setPaper('letter');

    if ($checklist->weekly_monthly) {
        $pdf->setOrientation('landscape');
    }

    $pdf->setOption('header-spacing', 30);
    $pdf->setOption('header-html', view('checklist.pdf.header')->with($export_data));
    $pdf->setOption('footer-html', view('report.pdf.footer'));

    return $pdf->download($save_path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your view `checklist.pdf.content`. In my experience with wkhtmltopdf, 99% of the time, the view was the issue.

Make sure that if you are using any image or external stylesheet in your view, their paths are properly defined. In case they are not, your HTML will work fine in your browser but using it for wkhtmltopdf will throw an error like this one.

In order to give paths for your images and external stylesheets, use following format:

```
<head>
    <link href="{{public_path()}}/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{public_path()}}/images/test.png" />
</body>
```

Of course, the exact path might differ based upon your folder configuration but they must be publically accessible and they should be accessed using the remote path.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thank you, my external stylesheet wasn't using the `public_path` and also there was an `onload()` event in my view which was causing the problem. I guess any  DOM Event also causes these problems.

Comment: yup they do, glad i could help